# Onedrive doesn't sync to the building icon, instead sync to the OneDrive - Tenant Name

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I tried syncing a Teams General folder to Onedrive in a new PC, but it is always syncing to Onedrive -  Icon in Onedrive [image]

We are using Microsoft Teams in the company, and we had added several Teams inside this organization.  Isn't it that each Teams have their own General folder which will contains files for each teams.  What I want is to sync this to Onedrive via the building icon, instead of Onedrive-,

[image]

The Building icon looks like this.  Is there a way to force onedrive to use the building icon and for me to select the default location for this instead of automatically assigning it to

OneDrive - \General\ folder which will be confusing if I have to sync many Teams.  Also we have some vba macros to run which will not work properly because of this change in file structure.

Before we just need to go to the teams File and go inside the general folder and then click sync and it will sync using the building icon.  Please help.

Comment: You might want to ask your companies IT about that issue. SU is not a place to ask about corporate networks.

Comment: Actually I work in the It department of our company.  It is just odd, because before I used to sync to the building icon before without problems.  Seems onedrive has updated and it is now syncing to the folder inside onedrive instead of the building icon.

Comment: The “building icon” path is used when you click “share” on the document library’s ribbon.  If a SharePoint document library is showing up in your OneDrive folder, then it’s been added as a shortcut in your OneDrive (it should be visible from your OneDrive in the browser too).

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your answer.  I want to the building icon to come out.  Can you please send me a screenshot of the share button on the document library's ribbon?  I cannot find it.  Thanks.